# How to run a code snippet once inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach

Let's assume I have a list and want to run a method only one time if the program enters the foreach. But important thing is initially I don't know if the loop empty or not.
What is the best practice to run a code snippet only one time inside foreach loop?

```
List<int> dummy = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int sum = 0;
foreach (int i in dummy)
{
    sum += i;

    DoJob(); //this method must run only once
}
```

I tried this but it did not look well

```
List<int> dummy = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int sum = 0;
foreach (int i in dummy)
    sum += i;

if (dummy.Count>0)
    DoJob();
```

Do you have any better idea?

Comment: What's the condition for running it once and also what's the specific job of `DoJob()` method?

Comment: Better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not use a standard for loop instead of a foreach?  You can then use the index and run your method based on index position.

Comment: If list is not empty, program steps into foreach. While looping inside foreach DoJob() method should only run for first loop but not for other loops.

Comment: @osman Why it doesn't look well.? How you expect it to look like?

Comment: @osman, does your code work as expected? If so, call it a day and don't bother optimizing just a couple of lines.

Comment: Sorry but this question should be closed. There's no real reason why you would like to run your method only once as soon as it enters the foreach loop or you aren't providing us enough information why you want to do it.

Comment: @rosko "you aren't providing us enough information why you want to do it" How is that relevant? The question is simple and clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be inside the loop? From what you've posted, it doesn't seem to.

```
List<int> dummy = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

if(dummy.Any())
    DoJob();

int sum = 0;
foreach (int i in dummy)
    sum += i;
```

Also, I'm assuming that snippet is just an example and not your actual code... if it is your actual code, you can use [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) (e.g., `int sum = dummy.Sum();`) instead of a `foreach` loop.

I'm also assuming your actual code uses an actual `List<T>` or some other concrete collection type. If it uses an `IEnumerable`, then the code above will iterate through the enumerable twice, which isn't recommended. If the enumerable actually represents a database query, you'll hit the database twice. So, if that's the case, just materialize the enumerable by calling [`.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) first.

Comment: Thanks, it is a little better than mine. I only wonder if there is another way to do it. But it seems i will delete this question.

Comment: @osman In my opinion, this seems very simple and readable. I wouldn't delete it, it might be helpful for someone else in the future.

Comment: yes you are right but I have -3 because of downvoters and I should delete this question.

Comment: @osman, you know one thing? you **can't** delete it after it has got answers. I was a bit lazy and misunderstood your question `;)`

Comment: @osman, I did that to my question, and it was rejected ;)

Comment: @osman, what? How do you know that?

Comment: @AmitJoki, sory I misunderstood you

Comment: @dcastro pls upvote the question and help it stay

Answer (score 1):

If using linq

```
        if (dummy != null && dummy.Any())
        {
            DoJob();
        }
```

If not using linq

```
        if (dummy != null &&  dummy.Count > 0)
        {
            DoJob();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

C# specification clearly states purpose of *foreach* statement ([8.8.4 The foreach statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)):

```
foreach (type identifier in expression) embedded-statement
```

> The foreach statement enumerates the elements of a collection,
>   executing an embedded statement for each element of the collection.

So, if you want something to be executed for *each* element of the collection, then put it in the embedded statement. If you want something to be executed only *once*, then putting it in a statement which executes for *each* element of the collection, and trying to avoid running it for each element - not very good idea.

Your last sample looks completely OK to me. Just remove braces (matter of taste though).